# Build system to compile every *.CS file in the project directory into one executable

Tags: c#, build, sublimetext3

I started to use Sublime Text (synced Packages folder in Linux and Windows via Dropbox), and I am creating some small C# projects without Visual Studio.

I can compile a single file with `csc` in windows or `gmcs` in linux, and have already compiled more than one file in linux from command line (outside sublime) with `gmsc *.cs`, which smartly resolved dependencies and created an executable named after the "topmost" class in the sources.

After fumbling a bit with Sublime Text build configuration files while [reading the docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html), and not having understood much, my question is:

> How should I configure Sublime Text (via JSON file) to build every *.cs file inside a project/directory into one single executable?

These projects, at least for now, are very simple, I am just separating the files to keep things organized.

Comment: Is your question how to compile multiple CS files with single call to CSC or something else ("csc /?" should help with former - just specify all files)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I want to perform the same as `gmcs *.cs; mono *.exe`, which works successfully in a bash script, but instead of running the script I want to put this in a `.build-system` file, the way it's supposed to be (but I don't know how).

Comment: I see - your question is about something I have no idea about, so that why I don't understand it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows consider [an approach to doing what you want on the Sublime Text forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3797#p17886).  Although it was posted with respect to ST2, I found that it works fine in ST3 too.

I think you will find the poster's specific approach easier to follow and adapt than trying to arrive at a solution from scratch after reading the Build Systems documentation.

Here is the `.sublime-build` file's contents - with **1)** the `cmd` path set for my Windows environment and **2)** `$file` replaced by `*.cs` to compile all `.cs` files in the current file's directory:

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:\\Bin\\Scripts\\sublimetext_csharp_builder.bat", "*.cs", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"], // NOTE: path set for my Windows environment
   //"cmd": ["\\path\\to\\sublimetext_csharp_builder.bat", "$file", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"],
   "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?)[(]([0-9]*),([0-9]*)[)]",
   "selector": "source.cs"
}
```

You can find [the related `sublimetext_csharp_builter.bat` file on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bdyck/1387512).  Below I have just **1)** removed its reliance on the Visual Studio batch file to set up environment variables, which really is not necessary as long as `csc` resolves in `%PATH%` or you use the full path to it and **2)** quoted its path to the resulting `exe`, which I found necessary for the path I was using (since it contained spaces):

```
:: Assumptions:
:: - Sublime Text has set the working directory and both the source and executable files
::   are in that directory
:: - The script is only capable of handling simple C# apps that do not reference 3rd-party
::   libraries

:: Inputs from Sublime Text
:: %1 - The full path and filename of the source file to build
:: %2 - The name of the executable file
@SET SRC_FILE="%1"
@SET EXE_NAME="%2"

csc %SRC_FILE% /nologo /debug:full /platform:x86
@IF errorlevel 1 GOTO end

:: Execute compiled binary if build was successful.
@ECHO.
@ECHO Executing %EXE_NAME%:
@ECHO.
:: NOTE: path quoted to accommodate spaces in it
@"%EXE_NAME%"
@%EXE_NAME%

:end
```

Comment: @heltonbiker: Also, a [blog post](http://www.jinweijie.com/sublimetext/net-build-system-for-sublime-text-2/) and [related code on GitHub](https://github.com/jinweijie/sublime-text-2-csharp-build) by Jin Weijie elaborates on this approach a bit - might also be worth checking out once you get the simple approach above working for your needs.